# Get the customer details in the Hosted Payment Page & return url

Tags: payment-gateway, zoho

I would like to integrate Zoho Subscription for our c# mvc web application. i am current having doubt in 2 scenarios at payment

1. Is there any way to make customer details on Hosted Payment Page Url ? Currently the fields are empty and it is creating new customer and new subscription.
2. After payment completed the page will be redirected to the return url (Which we will specify at the time of product creation). Is there any way to get the client details on return url as a query string parameter

   **Example: {return_url}/customer_id={Id}**

Please help me in understanding the above two scenarios. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Zoho Subscriptions](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/) supports two kinds of hosted pages: publicly accessible pages, and API-based pages.

Subscribing via a publicly accessible page will create a new customer and a new subscription every time.

However, if you'd like to create multiple subscriptions for a single customer, I suggest you to go with the [API Hosted Page](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#Hosted-Pages_Create_a_subscription). There you can create a subscription using "customer_id" (a unique identifier from Zoho Subscriptions to refer the customer).

On to your second query, in the redirect URL you can see a query parameter **hostedpage_id**, with this ID you can pull out the hosted page record which has all the required information of the customer and subscription.

Refer this [blog](https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/how-to-integrate-my-saas-application-with-zoho-subscriptions) to get more insights.